# How to add custom JavaScript to Azure AD B2C SignIn flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to add custom JS to Azure AD B2C flow, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow) I think 10 times, but still don't get it.

So far what I understand

1. I have a **Sign up and sign in (Recommended)** user flow
2. I enabled **JavaScript enforcing page layout (preview)** in properties
3. I selected 2.1.2 **Page Layout Version** for **Local account sign up page** (*This is the version of the packaged content containing HTML, CSS and JavaScript provided by Azure AD B2C*)

As far as I understand docs now I have the ability to somehow inject JavaScript into the sign-in page **without** using custom page content option.

The docs stated that to do so I need

> Include this code snippet into your sign-up or sign-in template for a self-asserted page

Where and how can I do that?

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Anything else is unclear?

Comment: @AllenWu hey, thx for the answer, I checked it but not yet deep-dived into it. I will try it in a week or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed somewhat vague.

In fact we have to use [custom page option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#1-create-your-html-content).

You need to include the code snippet into [your HTML content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#1-create-your-html-content).

See [this article](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-javascript-in-azure-ad-b2c-ui-customisation-6962c0991ea2) for detailed steps.

Comment: I understood that would be possible use Javascript without define a custom page. Docs are not very clear about this.